# When does a query start executing, and how to prevent it from executing?

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

When I have some code like this:

```
async f() {
  ...
  const result = await knex('table').select().where(...)
  ...
}
```

I have defined the query and am expecting the result in the same line. If instead I do this:

```
async f() {
  ...
  const query = knex('table').select().where(...) // line 1
  // do something else; line 2
  const result = await query // line 3
  ...
}
```

then does the query start executing at the first line or when the result is actually awaited?

From regular promise semantics, it would seem that query starts executing at line 1, and line 3 just awaits the result.

However, I suspect that this can't happen because `knex('table').select()` and `knex('table').select().where(...)` are both valid queries, and knex wouldn't have a way of knowing when the statement ends, so I'm not sure how it'll prepare the appropriate SQL query.

So does the query actually start executing at line 3 instead? Is this in violation of promise semantics?

And what's the correct way to define the query without executing it? Just to avoid awaiting it?

Comment: You can only really know by looking at the source code.

Comment: Why not make query a function? `query = () =>` and then use it later `await query()`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, that's actually a cleaner solution which wouldn't require knowing about library internals. I was just irked that the library doesn't behave in the expected way. You may post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a function, essentially saving the call for later.

```js
async f() {
  ...
  const query = () => knex('table').select().where(...) // line 1
  // do something else; line 2
  const result = await query() // line 3
  ...
}
```

The knex query shouldn't be run until the function `query` is called.
This approach is also library agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the answer in knex repository issues: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4163#issuecomment-746028366

> knex chain returns thenable. then method call starts query. await is just a syntax sugar on top of promises/thenables.
>
> `knex.schema.createTable( ... ).then(() => {})`

So yes, the query doesn't start executing until `.then` is called, and best way to keep it from executing is to avoid calling that.

Comment: For reference, this is the relevant portion in the source code: https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/2b0bebed612a36e063fe85dca70e8e747435d775/lib/builder-interface-augmenter.js#L23-L46 . But yeah, it was my assumption that the query would be started once `.then` is called. It's the only way a promise "knows" that it's being "consumed".